# How to remove "stop sharing" popup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, webrtc, opentok, tokbox, screensharing

I am using screen share extension to share screen on chrome with other users and when I share my screen with other users a popup open up with "stop sharing" button and never close even when screen share is closed.

I know that it should close automatically but now I need it to close programatically so is there any way to close this popup programatically.

I am referring below popup.

[image: I am referring this popup]

I have also tried below code to remove this popup:

window.stream.getTracks().forEach(function(e) {

```
        e.stop()
```

});

Comment: Please share some code, so that we can help you out.

Comment: It's not a popup in DOM It's chrome screen share extension popup which openup on screen share.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to remove it using jQuery. It's not an element on the webpage, this is a Chrome native popup.

The only way to remove it is to actually stop sharing. Make sure you are calling

`session.unpublish(publisher);
publisher.destroy();`

Comment: Yes, I use same above code to stop screen share but as I already said that I am using camera-filter API that preventing it to stop on stop screen share so I need other way to remove that popup.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the ID of the element, you can simply call

```
$("#elementID").remove()
```

Comment: You should not answer a question without a code shared. OP must edit his question first.

Comment: And why is so? If the question is clear enough and I can give him a suggestion, then maybe it'll help him.

Comment: A suggestion is not an answer and without code, you don't have the context of the need. The question is too broad. You should look help pages on "how to make a good question" and "how to make a good answer".

Comment: It's not a popup in DOM It's chrome screen share extension popup which openup on screen share.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
$('#your-id').hide();
```

or

```
$("#your-id").remove();
```

Comment: You should not answer a question without a code shared. OP must edit his question first.

Comment: It's not a popup in DOM It's chrome screen share extension popup which openup on screen share.